# adding 15 minutes to each time stamp from files

Tags: python

I'm having time stamps from file in the format

```
peakdata_20180821_1615.bz2
```

I'm crawling the data, and I need to add 15 minutes to each time stamps from months .
The problem is I have missing data for some files, so I want to just add 15 minutes to each day that ranges for example from august to october.

```
 for root, dirnames, files in os.walk(r"c:\ahmed\SpeedFT-meter1\peakdata"):
    for j in dirnames:
        for i in range(96):
            s = datetime.strptime(j, '%Y-%m-%d') + timedelta(minutes=15)
            timeStamps.append(s)
            directoary_names.append(root + r'\'' + 'peakdata_' + s.strftime("%Y%m%d_%M%H"))
```

Comment: whats your desired result? is it '20180821_1630' in the above example?

Comment: This question is not clear. What is your input and what is your output? Do the `peakdata_...` files already exist? Are we renaming them or are we creating new ones or are we just creating a list of file paths?

Answer (score 2):

First, extract the string containing the datetime from your filename. You got that right already. Then, convert the string to a Python `datetime` object. Finally, add a `timedelta` of 15 minutes:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> datetime.strptime('20180821_1615', '%Y%m%d_%H%M')
datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 21, 16, 15)
>>> datetime.strptime('20180821_1615', '%Y%m%d_%H%M') + timedelta(minutes=15)
datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 21, 16, 30)
```

Comment: I want to keep adding 15 minutes from 21.8 till 23.10

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that does what you want

```
def new_name(file, low=datetime(2018, 8, 1), high=datetime(2018, 9, 1)):
    """ Transform a filename of the form `peakdata_%Y%m%d_%H%M.bz2` to one 15 minutes
    later if it sits within the specified time range (August 2018 by default).

    Returns None on failure
    """
    try:
        dt = datetime.strptime(file, "peakdata_%Y%m%d_%H%M.bz2")
    except ValueError:
        return
    if low <= dt <= high:
        return (dt + timedelta(minutes=15)).strftime("peakdata_%Y%m%d_%H%M.bz2")
```

Simply apply it to each file you get, then if it is not `None`, `os.rename` that file.

Comment: I want to keep adding 15 minutes from 21.8 till 23.10

Comment: In which case use the function as `new_name(filename, low=datetime(2018,8,21), high=datetime(2018,10,23)`

Comment: I must say I am a little confused by your question now. What exactly is that supposed to do? You implied your input format is `peakdata_20180821_1615.bz2` but your code suggests it is actually the directory name of the form `'%Y-%m-%d'`. Which is it?